# Aligned text of the table cells

Tags: html-table, cell, vertical-alignment, equals, tablecell

I would like to know how can I make my text be aligned and centered the same way in every cell. Because if you see there is a slight difference between the first cell who got a link just under . I would my title to be on the same line without disturbing the responsive side and also the "same size cells" side (thanks to the table layout)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
td{
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  border:1px dotted red;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  td{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px dotted red;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:0px;
  }
}


p{font-family:'Varela Round';font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table>
        <tr><td><p>SOCIÉTÉS: 230</p></td></tr><tr><td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">+ En savoir plus</a></td></tr>
          <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
            <td>Part CAC 40 : 90</td></tr>
           <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
             <td>Part Filiales +100MK€: 120</td></tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td><p>CONTACT</p></td>
      <td><p>EMAIL NOMINATIF</p></td>
      <td><p>OPT OUT</p></td>
      <td><p>LIGNES DIRECTES/MOBILES</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just the element td to the css to have the text-align property as well:

CSS:

```
 p, td{
    font-family:'Varela Round';
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Also just a side note you for your js if you want to run your js code when the DOM is loaded jquery docs does not suggest you that document ready function instead they suggest:

JS

```
$(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});
```

Jquery Docs: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I followed your advice and I don't see any difference